# AngularJS tree control with draggable node

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hopefully this is the right question for this site. if not can you let me know where i should ask?

I am trying to find a tree control (in angularjs) that's easily customizable. (Should allow drag and drop on any node level)

I have been trying out [ng-nestable](https://github.com/kamilkp/ng-nestable) but havingg some issues since it is rebuilding all the nodes everytime an option is selected causing the UI not to retain any user values.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Did you contact the author of ng-nestable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree). That's close to doing what I want with a customisation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you are still looking you can check out this TreeView directive: [DragDrop in AngularJS TreeView](http://www.lidorsystems.com/products/web/studio/samples/treeview/drag-drop.aspx).

The sample shows how to drag-drop nodes in the same TreeView, and also between two TreeViews.